# SQLAlchemy ORM: Merge two rows based on one common value

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm

How can I merge two rows with same value in one column. Lets say I have a model with ~40 columns like below:

```
class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value_a = Column(String)
    value_b = Column(String)
    value_c = Column(String)
    ...
```

And I need to process each time ~500k rows of new data. Also each process creates a new table.

Once inserting the data first time(using `session.bulk_insert_mappings(Model, data)`) there are duplicated `value_c` values(max 2), but each time either it has `value_a` with some string and `value_b` is empty or `value_b` with some string and `value_a` is empty.

After initial insert:

```
| id | value_a | value_b | value_c |
| -- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
|  1 |   foo   |  None   |   xyz   |
|  2 |  None   |  bar    |   xyz   |
```

Having all rows I need to merge the rows with common `value_c` values together to get rid of duplicates.

After update:

```
| id | value_a | value_b | value_c |
| -- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
|  3 |   foo   |  bar    |   xyz   |
```

What is the most efficient way to do that? I was using from beginning `session.merge(row)` for each row but it is to slow and I decided to split it into insert and update stages.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to insert from a select statement that joins the not null a to the not null b.  Then after inserted the combined rows you can delete the old rows.  This matches the case you outlined exactly you might need to add more conditions to ignore other entries you might not want inserted or not deleted.  (ie. `(a, b, c) == (None, None, 'value')`)

I used `aliased` so that i can join the same table against itself.

```py
import sys

from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base, aliased
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, or_, and_, delete, insert


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


metadata = Base.metadata

class Model(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value_a = Column(String)
    value_b = Column(String)
    value_c = Column(String)

metadata.create_all(engine)


def print_models(session):
    for (model,) in session.execute(select(Model)).all():
        print(model.id, model.value_a, model.value_b, model.value_c)


with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    for (a, b, c) in [('foo', None, 'xyz'), (None, 'bar', 'xyz'), ('leave', 'it', 'asis')]:
        session.add(Model(value_a=a, value_b=b, value_c=c))
    session.flush()
    print_models(session)

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    #
    # Insert de-nulled entires.
    #
    left = aliased(Model)
    right = aliased(Model)
    nulls_joined_q = select(
        left.value_a,
        right.value_b,
        left.value_c
    ).distinct().select_from(
        left
    ).join(
        right,
        left.value_c == right.value_c
    ).where(
        and_(
            # Ignore entries with no C value.
            left.value_c != None,
            left.value_b == None,
            right.value_a == None))
    stmt = insert(
        Model.__table__
    ).from_select([
        "value_a",
        "value_b",
        "value_c"
    ], nulls_joined_q)
    session.execute(stmt)

    #
    # Remove null entries: All rows where value_c is NOT NULL and either value_a is empty or value b is empty.
    #
    # @NOTE: This deletes entries where value_a and value_b are BOTH null in the same row as well.
    #
    stmt = delete(Model.__table__).where(and_(
        # Ignore these like we did in insert.
        Model.value_c != None,
        or_(
            Model.value_a == None,
            Model.value_b == None),
        ))
    session.execute(stmt)
    session.flush()

    # Output
    print_models(session)
```

#### Output

```
1 foo None xyz
2 None bar xyz
3 leave it asis

#... then

3 leave it asis
4 foo bar xyz
```

#### Docs

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.from_select

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.delete

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.insert

Comment: Thank you for this answer! Seeing it is core based it should be fast enough for the amount of rows.